# How To Overwrite Meta Tags?

Tags: php, http-headers, meta-tags

I have index.php page with "default" meta tags, with switch function I call e.g. single_page.php and its looks something like `www.something.com/?page=single_page`.

how can I overwrite meta tags from index page with meta tags from single_page.php

```
$conlibrary="play/pages/"   ;                   
IF(!isset($_GET['page'])){ 
    $page = 'deafault'; 
} ELSE { 
    $page = $_GET['page']; 
    $findme = '&';
    $pos = strpos($page, $findme); 
    IF ($pos ===true) { 
        $data = explode("&", $data); 
        $dest =$conlibrary."/".$data[0].".php"; 
        IF (file_exists($dest)) {
            $page = $_GET['page']; 
        } ELSE {
            $page = '404'; 
        } 
    } ELSE { 
        $dest =$conlibrary."/".$page.".php"; 
        IF (file_exists($dest)) {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        } ELSE {
            $page = '404'; 
        } 
    } 
} 

include($conlibrary . $page .".php");
```

Comment: How can we answer this without seeing the relevant code? The simplest solution is likely to be another switch statement where you output the meta tags.

Comment: Can you give an example for what you mean by overwriting meta tags?

Comment: Did you know that you can indent your code to make it readable? :)

Comment: *What* meta tags do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to modify meta tags, and depending on the specific situation, my strategy would be to give the meta tags ID attributes and then make the alterations using Javascript, as in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/995408).

It doesn't work so well if the alterations need to be made *before* the page is sent to the browser; as PHP is not a primary language, my amateur instinct would be to simply use string variables for the "default" meta tags (rewriting the code if required) so that the included file could modify those strings as necessary.